# Geoserver SLD error - Premature end of file

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

Could you give me an advice with this SLD file http://pastebin.com/vyHLCFxq

If I add more feature content and I want to display the layer with this style it won´t display it , but It downloads wms.xml with this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
Premature end of file.
Details:
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.exception(Dispatcher.java:1675)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at org.geotools.styling.SLDParser.parseSLD(SLDParser.java:428)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse10(SLDHandler.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse(SLDHandler.java:141)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedStyle(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:1242)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getStyle(ResourcePool.java:1838)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.StyleInfoImpl.getStyle(StyleInfoImpl.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getStyle(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.getDefaultStyle(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:586)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:413)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:85)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1498)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:673)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:258)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.geotools.styling.SLDParser.parseSLD(SLDParser.java:416)
    ... 99 more
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I tried to validate that SLD in Geoserver but it hasn´t find any error. When I want preview style applied on style during code I get this:
[image]

any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Hard to say, go in the global GeoServer options and enable adding stack traces in the exceptions, then update your question with the full stack trace. By the looks of it, it seems that GeoServer did not actually get the full SLD file (you can also check the .sld file in your data directory)

Comment: I update my question with full error. Can you check now?

Comment: Well the SLD is valid according to: http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: I know, I tried valid button in Geoserver to check validity.

Comment: did you save the SLD through the GeoServer interface or did you save it directly to the filesystem from an external text editor? Looks like this could be a file encoding problem

Comment: I create sld style by Geoserver interface and next I copy parts of code step by step, because I want see which FeatureTypeStyle part break the style.

Comment: Looks like the stored configuration is broken somehow, GeoServer is going to parse the SLD on disk and finds what looks like an empty file  (or a file with strange characters at the beginning. Making a guess, you edited the file with windows notepad, which inserts a special non visible character, called BOM, at the beginning of files, breaking xml parsing in Java. See for example this discussion: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/187

Comment: I open this style in Notepad++ and when I check Encoding, I have selected "Encode in UTF-8". So I try click on "Convert to UTF-8" and save file. But still not working :/

Comment: Now I also try tool called File Bom detector, and no BOM was found.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue then... you might want to ask on the geoserver users list, maybe someone has seen it happen. I've just tried your style on a local geoserver running on Linux, it gets parsed without problems. Maybe it's a OS specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game, but I've encountered similar errors with character encoding problems in the SLD file vs. Geoserver. Of course encoding in UTF-8 should be taken care of in the actual SLD file. Commonly characters falsely converted from some non-latin alphabet/encoding to UTF-8 break the file prematurely, but this does not seem to be the case in your situation.

Looking at your SLD file, I would venture guessing that what broke it was the value 'Polygon' inside Title on row 11. Should've been probably written without the apostrophes.